# OpenVr: alternatives and compatibility

Tags: virtual-reality, steam, openvr

I am trying to figure out the OpenVR APIs capabilities and its exact role in VR contents development. 
So far i understood that games can be developed using OpenVR in order to be flexible on the kind of hardware used.

At this point I have a couple of questions that come to my mind:

- if one doesn't use OpenVR to develop a game in (let's say) unity, what else can he/she use? does the Steam plugin for unity use OpenVR?
- also, if I develop an OpenVR driver for a new kind of controller for VR games, what kind of games would be compatible with my new controller?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SteamVR is at this point synonymous with OpenVR. It is the only known server that implements the API. So yes, the SteamVR plugin will use OpenVR.

If you want to develop a VR controller, then I guess it would work in most games as long as you map it with the same axis. For example, [here is the mapping that Unity3d uses](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OpenVRControllers.html). You can make a vastly different controller, but don't count on it working with software that was not designed with it in mind.

Remember, that the controller API has not only tracking and axis, but also [it's 3d model](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/IVRRenderModels_Overview) that can be shown in VR. Quite a few (most?) apps don't use the API provided model, but have their own built in. This means people will most likely still see your controller in VR as the standard Vive wand. Try to model the grip at the same shape so at least that doesn't break immersion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Correct me if i am wrong, this means that if developers use the SteamVR plugin they make their game compatible with any openvr supported controller such as oculus touch, is that right?

Comment: Well... they should, but some may not consider this and things might look bad or even be useless. For example, let's say someone has [these kind of models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCOx93MzJLI) in game (just an example, no idea if they considered other controllers) - think how much will this break immersion if you see these, but have a oculus controller; or the help says press menu and you have to press the B button.  
Probably some of these differences can be game breakers (and can be considered bugs), but haven't yet seen one that bad.